# Not all code paths return a value - Enum practice

Tags: c#, enums, return

I've tried to execute a simple code just to study the enumeration topic.
Yet, I've faced this issue: "Not all code paths return a value".
Here is the code:

```
namespace ConsoleAppTest
{
    class Program
    {
        enum Seasons { Winter, Spring, Summer, Fall };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WhichSeason(3);
        }

        static Seasons WhichSeason(int month)
        {
            if (month >= 1 || month <= 3)
            {
                return Seasons.Winter;
            }
            else if (month >= 4 || month <= 6)
            {
                return Seasons.Spring;
            }
            else if (month >= 7 || month <= 9)
            {
                return Seasons.Summer;
            }
            else if (month >= 10 || month <= 12)
            {
                return Seasons.Fall;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I wonder what could cause this problem.
Thanks :)

Comment: What if `month` is `14`?

Comment: what should be returned in case `month == -1`?

Comment: I know, I didn't address mistyping yet, it's just for the purpose of learning enums

Comment: Unfortunately the computer doesn't understand that and is telling you "What if someone mistypes? You haven't handled that!"

Comment: @fubo In many cultures, yes, but other cultures use the convention of the code above. Of course, in the southern hemisphere, it is offset by six months.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should handle  the `else` case. Your `month` integer could also be `<1` or `>12`.

```
static Seasons WhichSeason(int month)
{
    if (month >= 1 && month <= 3)
    {
        return Seasons.Winter;
    }
    else if (month >= 4 && month <= 6)
    {
        return Seasons.Spring;
    }
    else if (month >= 7 && month <= 9)
    {
        return Seasons.Summer;
    }
    else if (month >= 10 && month <= 12)
    {
        return Seasons.Fall;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("invalid month");
    }
}
```

so if you call

```
WhichSeason(13); //throws exception
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't realize that it's mandatory to handle unwanted entries first, in order to execute the application. :)

Comment: @davidgpilot As soon as the return type of a method is anything _other_ than `void` (in your example `WhichSeason`, the return type is `Seasons`), all "paths" through the method body must `return` a value, or `throw` an exception (or loop ad infinitum). In other words, you are not allowed to reach the final end brace `}` of the method body. Remember, people will pick up the return value, for example `var answer = WhichSeason(3);` or `Console.WriteLine(WhichSeason(3));`. That could not work if the method would sometimes just exit with no returned value.

Answer (score 2):

What should be returned if `month`, say `-1` or `123`? You can solve the problem in two main ways, *silent*:

```
    // Please, notice "None"
    enum Seasons { None, Winter, Spring, Summer, Fall };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WhichSeason(3);
    }

    static Seasons WhichSeason(int month)
    {
        if (month >= 1 && month <= 3)
            return Seasons.Winter;
        else if (month >= 4 && month <= 6)
            return Seasons.Spring;
        else if (month >= 7 && month <= 9)
            return Seasons.Summer;
        else if (month >= 10 && month <= 12)
            return Seasons.Fall;
        else
            return Seasons.None;
    }
```

Or throwing appropriate *exception*, `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` in the case

```
    enum Seasons {  Winter, Spring, Summer, Fall };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WhichSeason(3);
    }

    static Seasons WhichSeason(int month)
    {
        if (month >= 1 && month <= 3)
            return Seasons.Winter;
        else if (month >= 4 && month <= 6)
            return Seasons.Spring;
        else if (month >= 7 && month <= 9)
            return Seasons.Summer;
        else if (month >= 10 && month <= 12)
            return Seasons.Fall;
        else
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
              "month", 
              "month must be in [1..12] range."); // Exception
    }
```

**Edit:** I've preserved `WhichSeason` *intact*, but it seems that you have a *logic error* in the implementation and the right routine should be

```
    static Seasons WhichSeason(int month)
    {
        if (month >= 1 && month <= 2 || month == 12) // Jan, Feb and Dec 
            return Seasons.Winter;
        else if (month >= 3 && month <= 5) // Mar-May
            return Seasons.Spring;
        else if (month >= 6 && month <= 8) // Jun-Aug
            return Seasons.Summer;
        else if (month >= 9 && month <= 11) // Sep-Nov
            return Seasons.Fall;
        else
            return Seasons.None;
    }
```

Comment: I personally prefer naming it using CamelCase :D

Answer (score 2):

You should add && operator in your logic and should also handle if input doesn't match in your described conditions -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{

     class Program
    {
        enum Seasons { Winter, Spring, Summer, Fall,NotAValidInput };

       public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(WhichSeason(-1));
        }

        static Seasons WhichSeason(int month)
        {
            if (month >= 1 && month <= 3)
            {
                return Seasons.Winter;
            }
            else if (month >= 4 && month <= 6)
            {
                return Seasons.Spring;
            }
            else if (month >= 7 && month <= 9)
            {
                return Seasons.Summer;
            }
            else if (month >= 10 && month <= 12)
            {
                return Seasons.Fall;
            }
            return Seasons.NotAValidInput;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a else block under else if . Method is not returning values in all cases and should be backed up with else .

Answer (score 0):

with switch

```
static Seasons WhichSeason(int month)
{
    switch (month)
    {           
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
            return Seasons.Spring;
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6:
            return Seasons.Summer;
        case 7:
        case 8:
        case 9:
            return Seasons.Fall;
        case 10:
        case 11:
        case 12:
            return Seasons.Winter;
        default:
            throw new Exception("The month is invalid!");
    }
}
```